# How to partially sort list of dictionary by dictionary value in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort dictionary by 'filename' if type ==1. For other items, don't touch them during sorting.

```
my_list = [
  {'fact9': {'filename': 'name2',
            'type': 1,
           }
  },
  {'fact4': {'filename': 'name33',
            'type': 4,
           }
  },
  {'fact5': {'filename': 'name1',
            'type': 1,
           }
  },
  {'fact6': {'filename': 'name12',
            'type': 2,
           }
 }
 ]
```

After sorting:

```
sorted_my_list = [
  {'fact5': {'filename': 'name1',
            'type': 1,
           }
  },
  {'fact4': {'filename': 'name33',
            'type': 4,
           }
  },
  {'fact9': {'filename': 'name2',
            'type': 1,
           }
  },
  {'fact6': {'filename': 'name12',
            'type': 2,
           }
  },
 ]
```

The code is something like following, but where to add type==1?

sorted_my_list = sorted(my_list, key = lambda k: k['filename'])

Comment: Did you try not doing it in one line? Would be much simple.

Comment: btw is that a list of strings and dicts?

Comment: you can't do it in one line, aim for 5 lines

Comment: Corrected original posted. Multiline is ok. How to do it?

Comment: Are you sure it's corrected? I bet it's supposed to be dict, not set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all the structure of your list assumes hierarchy but did not actually have it. To fix this, I suggest using another list/tuple to group the fact* and its dictionary together:

```py
[('fact9', {'filename': 'name2', 'type': 1}), ('fact4', {'filename': 'name33', 'type': 4}), ('fact5', {'filename': 'name1', 'type': 1}), ('fact6', {'filename': 'name12', 'type': 2})]
```

With this more structured list, you can perform the sort as you wish:

```py
tmp_list = sorted([x for x in my_list if x[1]['type']==1], key=lambda x:x[1]['filename'])
print(tmp_list)
sorted_my_list = [x if x[1]['type']!=1 else tmp_list.pop(0) for x in my_list]
print(sorted_my_list)
```

Output:

```py
[('fact5', {'filename': 'name1', 'type': 1}), ('fact9', {'filename': 'name2', 'type': 1})]
[('fact5', {'filename': 'name1', 'type': 1}), ('fact4', {'filename': 'name33', 'type': 4}), ('fact9', {'filename': 'name2', 'type': 1}), ('fact6', {'filename': 'name12', 'type': 2})]
```

As others pointed out in the comment it would be easier to write and read if you plan to do it in more lines. Also, you are not necessarily getting performance gain.

---

Update:

The question changed and the list of strings and dicts becomes a list of a dicts of dicts. However, I see little advantage of the dict approach to my tuple/list approach to get the hierarchy (and my solution get even messier when dealing with the dicts). Anyways now you have hierarchy so here you go:

```py
for d in my_list:
    for k,v in d.items():
        if v['type'] == 1:
            tmp_list.append({k:v})
tmp_list = sorted(tmp_list, key=lambda x:[i['filename'] for i in x.values()])
print(tmp_list)
sorted_my_list = [x if [i['type'] for i in x.values()][0]!=1 else tmp_list.pop(0) for x in my_list]
print(sorted_my_list)
```

Output:

```py
[{'fact5': {'filename': 'name1', 'type': 1}}, {'fact9': {'filename': 'name2', 'type': 1}}]
[{'fact5': {'filename': 'name1', 'type': 1}}, {'fact4': {'filename': 'name33', 'type': 4}}, {'fact9': {'filename': 'name2', 'type': 1}}, {'fact6': {'filename': 'name12', 'type': 2}}]
```

Note that the code above assumes that you only have a single entry(key/value pair) in the outermost dict, which seems to be the case, or it would make little sense since you would be sort dicts.

Comment: Thank you. This should work, and agreed with your tuple suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't try to do this with the sorted() functions. Try doing it this way:
First filter all the type 1's out of the dict:

```
filtered_items = {}
for fact in my_list:
    if my_list[fact]['type'] == 1:
        filtered_items[fact] = my_list[fact]
        del my_list[fact]
```

After that you add my_list to the filtered items so they are at the end and the type 1's are first

```
filter_items.update(my_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I think filtered_items should be picked up by type==1, not by 'name1'. After sorted, it will loose original position when put it back, as this info is not kept.